# Planetary rotation in opengl es 2.0

Tags: android, rotation, opengl-es-2.0

In opengl es 2.0 for android, how can I make an object that is already rotating around its own axis, rotate around a static object, like a planet?

Answer (score 0):

So if you are trying to create something like solar system. Consider origins of both sphere to be same initially. Now translate second sphere by radius amount (make a taranslation matrix and multiply with current modelview matrix of second sphere).  Again for rotation create a rotation matrix and multiply result of step one with this one. Apply this matrix to second sphere.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical example of father/son(s) relation.

The "planet" becomes the father while the "moon" becomes the child.

Using OpenGL Es 2.0 you have for sure functions to rotate/translate and push/pop the matrices.

Having said so, would be something like this (in pseudo code)

PUSH MATRIX

Translate (Father)

Rotate (Father)

PUSH MATRIX

Translate (Child)

Rotate (Child)

Render (Child)

POP MATRIX

Render (Father)

POP MATRIX

I hope this helps in some way.

Cheers
Maurizio